# Make the hidden image appear after pressing the browser refresh, with just one click

Tags: javascript, html, css, session-storage

With this code below, I hide the image after pressing the button click. When I navigate between other pages, the image should remain hidden. This is working fine. When the user clicks on browser refresh, the image should appear again. The problem is that the image is only appearing after the user clicks twice on refresh. I would like it to appear after a single click. Below is a summary for clarity.

- When clicking the button, the image is hidden -> It's working fine!
- When browsing other pages and coming back to this page, the image should remain hidden -> It's working fine!
- When the user clicks on the browser refresh, the image should appear -> This is NOT working well, as the image is only appearing after the browser refresh is double-clicked. I want the image to appear with a single click on browser refresh.

  ```
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>

        <style>
            .btn-close {
                width: 166px;
                height: 44px;
                margin-top: 12px;
                font-size: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="img-container">
            <img class="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/163236/luxury-yacht-boat-speed-water-163236.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="">
            <button class="btn-close">Fechar</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            (function () {
                const image = document.querySelector('.img')
                const btnClose = document.querySelector('.btn-close')
                let visibility = sessionStorage.getItem("visibility")

                if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
                    visibility = sessionStorage.getItem("visibility")
                    let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                    let lastLoadedTime = sessionStorage.getItem('lastLoadedTime');
                    sessionStorage.setItem("visibility", "visible");
                    image.style.display = "block"
                    if (lastLoadedTime && (currentTime - lastLoadedTime) < 1000) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("visibility", "visible");
                        image.style.display = "block"
                    }

                    sessionStorage.setItem('lastLoadedTime', currentTime);
                }

                btnClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    image.style.display = "none"
                    sessionStorage.setItem("visibility", "invisible");
                })

                if (visibility == "invisible") {
                    image.style.display = "none"
                } else if (visibility == "visible") {
                    image.style.display = "block"
                }
            })()

        </script>
    </body>



    </html>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated and checked it should work now:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    .btn-close {
      width: 166px;
      height: 44px;
      margin-top: 12px;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/163236/luxury-yacht-boat-speed-water-163236.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1&cache_bust=<%= new Date().getTime() %>" alt="">
    <button class="btn-close">Fechar</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    (function () {
      const image = document.querySelector('.img');
      const btnClose = document.querySelector('.btn-close');
      let visibility = sessionStorage.getItem('visibility');

      if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
        let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        let lastLoadedTime = sessionStorage.getItem('lastLoadedTime');
        if (lastLoadedTime && (currentTime - lastLoadedTime) < 1000) {
          visibility = sessionStorage.getItem('visibility');
          image.style.display = visibility === 'visible' ? 'block' : 'none';
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem('visibility', 'visible');
          visibility = 'visible';
          image.style.display = 'block';
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem('lastLoadedTime', currentTime);
      }

      btnClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
        image.style.display = 'none';
        sessionStorage.setItem('visibility', 'invisible');
      });

      if (visibility === 'invisible') {
        image.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        image.style.display = 'block';
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Your solution caused a side effect. Indeed, the image reappeared, with just one click, but it had the side effect of now the image reappearing after navigating between other pages and coming back to this one. There was this rule: When browsing other pages and coming back to this page, the image should remain hidden. This rule was working in my code.

Comment: Try the new code

Comment: Now it works! Congratulations!